# Is there a Magic the Gathering card that resembles The Hanged Man Tarot card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, tarot

I have been looking for any card which has artwork resembling an entity dangling upside down but with no luck.

Potential ideas could be something to do with the Rakdos circus, an over-confident assassin, someone entangled by a snare or someone slacking on a job. I have tried searching in-regards to card name (e.g. bound, hang, hanged, tangled, trap, snare, etc.).

Failing this, I'm also trying to look for a card that fits one or more of these properties in relation to The Hanged Man: "Pause, surrender, letting go, new perspectives".

[image: The Hanged Man Tarot]

Comment: "Subcontract" has an old lady hanging from the ceiling Mission Impossible style, while poisoning some tea.

Answer (score 3):

Relating partially to the overconfident assassin part of your post there is always 
[Robber of the Rich](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=473100)

[image: Robber of the Rich card image]

Answer (score 0):

The best card I could find for "hanging upside down" was oddly enough [Plummet](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlummet%5d).

[image]

Obviously the flavor is off, but they are tied up and upside down.

For other options, you might consider the [Gallows at Willow Hill](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGallows%20at%20Willow%20Hill%5d), which features no hanged characters in the art, but involves quite a bit of hanging in the flavor.  Similarly, [Hanged Executioner](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHanged%20Executioner%5d) appears to show a hanged person in the post-hanging state.

Finally, if you want a card that exemplifies "Pause, surrender, letting go, new perspectives", then I recommend [Pacifism](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPacifism%5d).  The original Mirage art even looks like a Tarot card, although you probably already have a card for the Fool.

Answer (score 0):

I was rather sure that there's a Giant card that resembles what you're looking for closely, and I somewhat found some matches... except none of those is serious enough for what I would assume your purposes are, I'm afraid:

- [Lowland Oaf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLowland%20Oaf%5d)
- [Ravenous Giant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRavenous%20Giant%5d)

Another card that might fit better is [Nissa's Defeat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNissa%27s%5d%2b%5bDefeat%5d), which seems to fit halfway on both the visual and "Pause, surrender, letting go, new perspectives" angle (although of course, Nissa would be a "hanged woman").

[image: Nissa's Defeat]